# How is divideMessage working

Tags: java, android

I have an SMS application and one user from Greek is reporting an issue with the national characters. Everything works, but when he is typing common Greek letters like alfa, beta in my application the SMS is split into two parts after 70 characters. But if he is using the built-in default SMS application he can type 160 characters before it splits.

```
    ArrayList<String> msgTexts = null;
    SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();

    msgTexts = sms.divideMessage(sBuf);
```

How can I make divideMessage and sendMultipartTextMessage to work properly with the Greek national characters? I haven't heard anyone else reporting this around the word.

- Mobile: samsung GT S7580 with android 4.2.2
- Built-in default SMS application is used
- Greek language is used in mobile settings

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You need to read this http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short_Message_Service especially "Message size" chapter

> Short messages can be encoded using a variety of alphabets: the
>   default GSM 7-bit alphabet, the 8-bit data alphabet, and the 16-bit
>   UCS-2 alphabet. **Depending on which alphabet the subscriber has
>   configured in the handset, this leads to the maximum individual short
>   message sizes of 160 7-bit characters, 140 8-bit characters, or 70
>   16-bit characters.**

Comment: ok, thank you. I thought divideMessage was dealing with this for me.

Comment: Many SMS apps offer feature to convert accented characters to plan one i.e. `ą` =>  'a', `ł` => `l` etc, whenever language allows just for that reason - to prevent using UTF encoding and fit more chars per single message.

Answer (score 0):

> Transmission of short messages between the SMSC and the handset is
>   done whenever using the Mobile Application Part (MAP) of the SS7
>   protocol.[43] Messages are sent with the MAP MO- and MT-ForwardSM
>   operations, whose payload length is limited by the constraints of the
>   signaling protocol to precisely 140 octets (140 octets * 8 bits /
>   octet = 1120 bits). Short messages can be encoded using a variety of
>   alphabets: the default GSM 7-bit alphabet, the 8-bit data alphabet,
>   and the 16-bit UCS-2 alphabet.[44] Depending on which alphabet the
>   subscriber has configured in the handset, this leads to the maximum
>   individual short message sizes of 160 7-bit characters, 140 8-bit
>   characters, or 70 16-bit characters. GSM 7-bit alphabet support is
>   mandatory for GSM handsets and network elements,[44] but characters in
>   languages such as Arabic, Chinese, Korean, Japanese, or Cyrillic
>   alphabet languages (e.g., Ukrainian, Serbian, Bulgarian, etc.) must be
>   encoded using the 16-bit UCS-2 character encoding (see Unicode).
>   Routing data and other metadata is additional to the payload size.

[@Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short_Message_Service)